# How to show appropriate page on mobile

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I want to capture some blog from some blog sites. I know to use HttpClient to get the html string, and then use [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to capture the content under the specific html tag. But if you use WebView to show this html string, you will find that it's not good in mobile. For example, css style will not be loaded correctly. Some code-blocks will not auto wrap. Some pictures will not show (It will show x).

Some advertisements also will show, but I don't want it.

Do anyone know how to get it? Any suggestions will be apprieciate.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the html string through something like [Google Mobilizer](http://www.google.com/gwt/n).  This should make a more mobile friendly html string which you can then use the Agility pack to 'unpack'

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should capture the HTML page and all its associated resources: CSS files, images, scripts, ...
And then updates the HTML content so that resources are retrieved from your local data storage (for example, relative URL will not work anymore if you saved the HTML page locally).

You may also send your HTTP Request with a `User-Agent` header that corresponds to the one used by Microsoft browser in order to obtain the corresponding version from the website (if they do some kind of User-Agent sniffing).